# Why is $E[(Y-f(X))^2] = E[(Y-f(X))^T(Y-f(X))]$ in derivation of the regression function f?

Tags: linear-algebra, self-learning, linear-regression

I am working through Chapter 2 of *The Elements of Statistical Learning* (Hastie, Tibshirani, Friedman). I have problems following the authors as they analytically derive the regression coefficients $\beta$ for the regression function $f$. $x$ is a column vector of predictors. In the book, these are the equations (2.9) together with (2.15) and (2.16).

$$ f:\mathbb{R}^p\rightarrow\mathbb{R},\quad f(x) = x^T\beta $$

It's done by finding the minimum of the Expected Prediction Error $\mathrm{EPE}$

$$ \frac{\partial \mathrm{EPE}}{\partial \beta} = 0 \implies \text{Minimal EPE for this value of}\ \beta $$

This problem is discussed [in a question at Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/89251). However, there, the OP proposes the following transformations to arrive at a solution, where I don't understand the first transformation (marked by (*)). $X\in\mathbb{R}^p$ is a real valued random vector of predictors, $Y \in\mathbb{R}$ is a real valued random output variable.

Quote of question, $\bigcirc^T$ inserted as mentioned in answer by @bill_e:

> $$ EPE(f) = E[(Y-f(X))^2] $$
>   $$ EPE(f) = E[(Y-X^T\beta)^T(Y-X^T\beta)] 
> \tag{*}$$
>   [...]

Why is $(Y-X^T\beta)^2 = (Y-X^T\beta)^T(Y-X^T\beta)$ here? I always thought $A^2$ for a vector is the dot product of the vector with itself, so $A^2 = |A|\cdot|A|\cdot \cos\ 0° = |A|^2$?

Comment: $Y \in \mathbb{R}$, so $(Y-X^T\beta)^T = (Y-X^T\beta) \in \mathbb{R} $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am more used to writing $$\|A\|^2 = A^TA$$

Notice that here we have $f(X)=X^T\beta$, let $A = Y-X^T\beta$,

$$\| Y - f(X)\|^2 = \|Y-X^T\beta \|^2=\|A\|^2=A^TA=(Y-X^T\beta)^T(Y-X^T\beta)$$

Comment: Ah, I get it now. If $A$ is a column vector, $\|A\| = \sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2+\ldots+a_n^2}$ is the absolute value of $A$, so $\|A\|^2 = a_1^2+a_2^2+\ldots+a_n^2 = A^T A$. But how do I know that the authors mean the absolute value when they write $A^2$ (or, as in this case, $(Y-X^T\beta)^2$)? Is this common? Are there alternative interpretations of $A^2$ on which I have to decide by what makes sense?

Comment: Without context, it could have meant squaring a vector component wise. Usually, the convention is consistent throughout a book. I do see that convention sometimes and I can understand it though I don't write that to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thanks for these precious tips!